# Create PSCredential from AzureAD User

Tags: powershell, credentials, azure-powershell, runas

I don't know why I can't figure this out, this can't be as hard as I'm making it. I'm trying to create a powershell script that will elevate itself using explicit credentials from AzureAD. I create a PSCredential object with:

```
$ss = ConvertTo-SecureString "p@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object PSCredential -ArgumentList 'username@domain.com', $ss
Start-Process PowerShell -Credential $cred "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`""
exit;
```

When I execute this I get `Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The user name or password is incorrect.`

I know the username and password *are* correct but I am guessing that it has to do with the fact that this is an AzureAD user? Do I have to format the AzureAD username differently? I've tried reformatting it every way I can think of. I've tried using `Connect-AzureAD` and using `Get-AzureADUser` to try to see if I could use some property of that to sign in but I'm coming up empty.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

With `Start-Process` you must specify username in format "DOMAIN\user". I am not sure where from this limitation is coming.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply to an AzureAD credential. I've tried both `domain\username` and `domain.com\username` and both still give the same error. This is my first time using AzureAD instead of a local domain so I'm a bit lost with this. When I look at portal.azure.com, it shows that my device is "Azure AD Joined" but in System Properties it's not in a domain there because I guess Azure is handled differently being cloud-based.

Comment: Can you try that workgroup name as domain name in your full username, like "WORKGROUP\username"?

Comment: That also did not work, unfortunately. I wonder if I have to query for the Azure AD object first? Idk, I'm just going around and manually doing this for now :( Thanks for all of your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Is the domain that the azure ad user account you are trying to run the command as accessible to the domain that your machine is connected to?  Without more information, I can only speculate that powershell is throwing the error because it does not recognize the user or the domain the user is a member of.

Comment: The machine is joined to the same AzureAD domain as the user account that I'm trying to log in with. I've just started this work for a nonprofit that had no IT department previously. They've got offices spread across a large geographical area and they are going remote now also. The computers have no remote access software, no naming conventions, and the end users are not allowed local admin privileges. I want a script that I can run quickly and easily to rename the computer and install the remote access software. From what you're seeing, should an AzureAD username work in my script as written?

Comment: To add, when I put Connect-AzureAD at the start of the script and use the same credentials as I have in the script to log in to Azure, I am able to log on and it prints out my user, but then gives me the error when it gets to the part in the script where credentials are supplied.

I get: `Account: username@domain.com | Environment: AzureCloud | TenantId: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx | AccountType: User`